# Правильно ли расставлены запятые? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, причастный-оборот

*Карьерист, раздражающий таких же, как он, карьеристов.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, запятые расставлены правильно.
*Раздражающий таких же, как он, карьеристов* — это причастный оборот, стоящий **после** определяемого слова "карьерист"; ставим перед ним запятую.
*Как он* — сравнительный оборот, находящийся внутри причастного; обрамляем запятыми (при перестановке:  раздражающий таких же карьеристов, как он).

Да, да, несомненно, но и все-таки там ― мама, **вечно раздражающая своим тихим голосом, покорностью и безысходностью,** но мама, ма-ма… [Булат Окуджава. Упраздненный театр (1989-1993)]
И в том же Марселе, где он родился, есть новые тысячи **таких же, как он,** мальчишек. [Александр Волков. Год берлинского чуда // «Знание - сила», 2006]

[**такой(,) как**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_722), *местоимение + союз*